# Anonymous new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() can be replaced with lambda, Java11

Tags: java

I'm currently using inteliJ and have constructed the following method however the ide seems to be recommending the following: 'Anonymous new ExpectedCondition() can be replaced with lambda'

Any ideas how I can change the below method to use lambda?

```
public void waitForPageLoaded() {
    ExpectedCondition<Boolean> expectation = new
            ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
                public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
                    return ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").toString().equals("complete");
                }
            };
    try {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), 30);
        wait.until(expectation);
    } catch (Throwable error) {
        Assert.fail("Timed out waiting for Page Load Request to complete.");
    }
```

Please note I'am using Java11. 
Thanks for your help

Comment: by rewriting it ... do you know how to write code with lambda in Java?

Comment: if IntelliJ is telling you it can be converted to lambda, it means it knows already how to do it, just tell intelliJ to do the conversion to lambda for you :)

Comment: Hit alt + enter and it will prompt you to do it automatically

Comment: perfect thanks for your help!